# Java 8 update 161 breaks HTTPClient Kerberos authentication

Tags: java, security, authentication, kerberos, apache-httpclient-4.x

My HTTPClient Kerberos authentication set up is similar to [this one](https://github.com/Lab-Work/AwesomeStitch/blob/master/libs/httpcomponents-client-4.2.5/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientKerberosAuthentication.java). My login.conf looks like this:

```
com.sun.security.jgss.login {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useTicketCache=true
  useKeyTab=true
  storeKey=true
  keyTab=<keytab>
  principal=<principal>;
};
com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useTicketCache=true
  useKeyTab=true
  storeKey=true
  keyTab=<principal>
  principal=<keytab>;
};
com.sun.security.jgss.accept {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useTicketCache=true
  useKeyTab=true
  storeKey=true
  keyTab=<keytab>
  principal=<principal>;
};
```

This setup has been working for me with jdk8u151, but Oracle released jdk8u161 recently, and it no longer works. Debug looks like this:

Comparing debug logs, jdk8u161 stops at this line:

> CCacheInputStream: readFlags()

while jdk8u151 follows that line with

> unsupported key type found the default TGT: 18

I added

```
default_tkt_enctypes = aes128-cts des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
default_tgs_enctypes = aes128-cts des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
permitted_enctypes = aes128-cts des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
```

to `krb5.conf`, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found my own answer:

- Remove all `useTicketCache=true` from login.conf
- Add `rc4-hmac` to `default_tkt_enctypes`, `default_tgs_enctypes`, and `permitted_enctypes`

login.conf now looks like this:

```
com.sun.security.jgss.login {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab=true
  storeKey=true
  keyTab=<keytab>
  principal=<principal>;
};
com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab=true
  storeKey=true
  keyTab=<keytab>
  principal=<principal>;
};
com.sun.security.jgss.accept {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab=true
  storeKey=true
  keyTab=<keytab>
  principal=<principal>;
};
```

and krb5.conf:

```
[libdefaults]
  ...
  default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
  default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
  permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
  ...
```

Comment: It says I can do that in 2 days.

Comment: Be careful about re-enabling RC4. This enctype is now considered weak / compromised. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7465. It would be better to find out which Kerberos Component (client, server, KDC, TGS etc) is still using RC4, and reconfigure that to use a strong encryption type (e.g. AES256).